# URL rewrite problem

Tags: magento-1.9, url-rewrite

I am trying to rewrite product URL's (removing the products from  my site) but am not able to edit the target path.

When I try to do this via creating a custom rewrite I get an error:

> Request path for specified store already exists.

Could this be due to previous rewrites of the same product from my previous website to my current?

In Rewrite Management I can see historical rewrites of this product from my old site.

Any suggestions please?